# Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory

Tags: magento2, cli

I created module magento 2,but module can't run and errors exist `Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade` from the Magento root directory. "

i tried to run command `bin/magento setup:upgrade` but not success, 
appeared another error:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade /usr/bin/env: ‘php’: No such file or directory
```

I am using window 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to run this command from the root directory :

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

after upgrade you can flush the cache:

```
php -f bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: thanks for answer  but it errors same this:
bash: php: command not found

Comment: Make sure your syntax , naming convention and everything is fine. check if there is any typo mistake and check the logs . Often this is caused by typo, Still exists !!!, post your module code for reference.

Comment: pls help me check this code:
https://github.com/quangnghiasl995/magento2-helloworld
i think code correct

Comment: Try adding the path to `php`. Run `which php` to find the path.

Comment: @Manashvi birla thanks for reply ....its working for me

Comment: After running `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` I get `There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace.`

Answer (score 7):

I hope this will help you

If you are using wamp server on windows then

`C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12>php.exe C:\wamp\www\<Magento root directory>\bin\magento setup:upgrade` in your CLI.

Comment: im using xampp
git bash in xampp/htdocs/magento root directory/ then run command bin/magento setup:upgrade

Answer (score 3):

I follow these steps to solve this issue on my project (reference source: https://magentoexplorer.com/please-upgrade-your-database-run-binmagento-setupupgrade-from-the-magento-root-directory)

**Step 1** Remove unused module table from database.
[image]

Only remove modules that are not installed on your magento store

**Step 2**. Go to your Magento 2 root folder and open the Git Bash. Run the following command from your ssh command interface

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Also

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Hope this helps with your situation

Comment: what is this table,if you include the table name it would be great understanding for reader

Comment: The table is called `setup_module` if you still need it :p